# How to flip Product image on hover in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to change or flip the product image on the mouse-over product image. So please suggest any WordPress plugin or any code that achieve that effect (also suggest file path of changes be made).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add custom image field, put 2 images (*eg. featured and from custom field*) in wrapper and change tier `z-index` on wrapper `hover`....
CSS:

```
.product-image--wrapper .img1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.product-image--wrapper .img2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.product-image--wrapper:hover .img2 {
z-index: 2;
}
```

..or just install: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-image-flipper/ and follow: http://www.themelocation.com/how-to-flip-product-image-on-hover-in-woocommerce/

EDIT:

we fix WooCommerce Product Image Flipper with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( 'ul.products li.pif-has-gallery a:first-child' ).hover( function() {
        jQuery( this ).find( '.wp-post-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeInDown' ).addClass( 'animated fadeOutUp' );
        jQuery( this ).find( '.secondary-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeOutUp' ).addClass( 'animated fadeInDown' );
    }, function() {
        jQuery( this ).find( '.wp-post-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeOutUp' ).addClass( 'fadeInDown' );
        jQuery( this ).find( '.secondary-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeInDown' ).addClass( 'fadeOutUp' );
    });
});
```

Comment: ..you working on woocommerce? (you was write "plugin" so i think you using WP) :)

Comment: You can make it custom with custom fields and edit woocommerce **or** install: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-image-flipper/

Comment: I prefer custom options..you need customise woocommerce..make two custom field and include in your query, use css from answer.

Comment: where should i add these two customs fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95658/discussion-between-thestreets93-and-dnyan).

Answer (score 0):

I am using WordPress 4.5.3 with woo-commerce 2.6.1 and it's working well, even though that WordPress says the plugin it's not compatible so I take my own risk.

Try to add `animate.css` by daneden on your function, I don't know if this related or not, but if I commented on the animate.css on the `function.php`, the plugin didn't work well.

oh once more, I think it's better you change fadeInDown/fadeOutUp, I try to use it just fadeIn/fadeOut, using Down and Up makes weird, IMOO.

Answer (score 0):

As the product image flipper is pretty outdated, this tool works fine with my woocommerce shop: WC Secondary Product Thumbnail
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-secondary-product-thumbnail/

(hope it helps, as it took me ages to find a working plugin. Magni image flipper is also strange, as it endlessly flips the images, which is really not what I would expect)

Answer (score -1):

Extended Answer of @Matej Đaković=>

First install the  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-image-flipper/ plugin and then place the code in your footer.php

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( '.product-image' ).hover( function() {
        jQuery( this ).find( '.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail' ).removeClass( 'fadeIn' ).addClass( 'animated fadeOut' );
        jQuery( this ).find( '.secondary-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeOut' ).addClass( 'animated fadeIn' );
    }, function() {
        jQuery( this ).find( '.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail' ).removeClass( 'fadeOut' ).addClass( 'fadeIn' );
        jQuery( this ).find( '.secondary-image' ).removeClass( 'fadeIn' ).addClass( 'fadeOut' );
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was new and I did not know properly how to structure the code section.