# Switch product image on hover on WooCommerce archive page by category

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to change product image on hover on archive pages for products from Merch category. (Product cover image should be changed to first gallery photo)

I took the following code form here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088615/switch-product-image-on-hover-on-woocommerce-archive-page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/). But it affects all products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_on_hover_shop_loop_image' ) ; 

function add_on_hover_shop_loop_image() {

    $image_id = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids()[1] ; 

    if ( $image_id ) {

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id ) ;

    } else {  //assuming not all products have galleries set

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( wc_get_product()->get_image_id() ) ; 

    }

}
```

```
/* CUSTOM ON-HOVER IMAGE */
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img { 
    /* FORMAT ALL IMAGES TO FILL EQUIVALENT SPACE,
    to remove jitter on replacement */
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: block
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a:hover img:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm sorry for a newbie question but I can't figure out how to apply it for 'merch' product category. My attempt:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_on_hover_shop_loop_image' ) ; 

function add_on_hover_shop_loop_image() {
  
  global $product;
   $product_id = $product->get_id();
   if ( has_term( 'merch', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
      
     $image_id = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids()[1] ; 

    if ( $image_id ) {

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id ) ;

    } 
      
      else {  //assuming not all products have galleries set

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( wc_get_product()->get_image_id() ) ; 

    }

}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
Maybe somebody needs this code. Just replace 'merch' with your category name:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_on_hover_shop_loop_image' ) ; 

function add_on_hover_shop_loop_image() {
  
    
        if (has_term( 'merch', 'product_cat')){

    $image_id = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids()[1] ; 

    if ( $image_id ) {

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id ) ;

    } else {  //assuming not all products have galleries set

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( wc_get_product()->get_image_id() ) ; 

    }

}
}
```

Add 'merch-class' to products from 'merch' category:

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes, $class, $product_id) {
 if(is_product_category('merch')) {
     //only add these classes if we're on a product category page.
     $classes = array_merge(['merch-class'], $classes);
 }
 return $classes;
},10,3);
```

CSS (Replace 'merch-class'  with your class):

```
/* CUSTOM ON-HOVER IMAGE */
li.merch-class  a img { 
    /* FORMAT ALL IMAGES TO FILL EQUIVALENT SPACE,
    to remove jitter on replacement */
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
li.merch-class  a img:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}
li.merch-class    a:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: block
}
li.merch-class  a:hover img:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```